# Dropdown Divs Aligning with Heading Button

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently trying to develop a three button system to display the three collectibles within my game's website. I currently have the buttons ready, but the one on the right flies off the screen, and the middle one looks off.

I am trying to create a look in which the left button has the dropdown content as it is, the middle with the dropdown content aligned centre, and the right with the dropdown content mirroring the left one but going from right, to left.

Here is the current website with the 'Collectibles' section a little ways down the home page:
https://timeandtimeagain.manakeep.com/

Here is the HTML code for the block:
https://pastebin.com/mEECfh2T

Here is the CSS code for the block:

```
#artifactsButton p {
     padding: 5px;
     text-align: center;
   }

#floraButton p {
     text-align: right;
     word-wrap: break-word;

  }

 #collectiblesHeader {
   text-align: center;
  }

 #artifactsButton {
   float: left;
      }

 #floraButton {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 10px;
 }

 #lettersButton {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 290px;
 }

 .dropbtn {
   font-size: 28px; 
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   background-color: inherit;
   font-family: inherit; 
   margin: 0; 
 }

 .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: grey;
 }


 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   max-width: 500px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
 }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the screenshots.

Comment: https://timeandtimeagain.manakeep.com/
Sorry, this is the site for the game. Scroll down a little to find the 'Collectibles' section.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained. Even if you don't yet have enough reputation to post images, you can upload them to Stack's own Imgur where it will be easy for someone with more reputation to inline them if they look okay.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to set the `.dropdown` class the `position: relative;`.
Then you can work with the `absolute` attribute.

Example:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

#artifactsButton .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

#lettersButton .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

#floraButton .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    top: 100%;
    left: -160px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

In the case of `#floraButton`, you'll have to set the `left` manual, I set it from my resolution.

This is a solution, but I recommend you to distribute the divs in a better way. With `flexbox` for example.